# How to tell when python webbrowser has finished playing video

Tags: python, youtube, python-os, python-webbrowser

So I using code like this to open a YouTube link with webbrowser in python:

```
webbrowser.open("youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoLink)
```

and I need to tell when the video finishes so I can then do:

```
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM chrome.exe")
```

Does anyone know how to tell when the video has finished?